# Angular2: Object doesn't support this action in Microsoft Edge browser

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, microsoft-edge, angular-promise

My angular2 application throws exception stating **Object doesn't support this action** only in Microsoft edge. Please check the below image:

[image]

[image]

I debugged and found out that the exception is thrown at promise then code. To be more specific, I am getting the error at then on below code:

```
this.dataLayerService
            .postLogin(this.model, this.postURL)
            .then(usermasterResponse => this.setToken(usermasterResponse))
            .catch(error => {
                  this.toastCommunicationService.setMessage(error, "",
                    this.toastCommunicationService.errorType)
            });
```

I have also added below script in the index.html file, but it was also in vain.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.34.1/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Related posts - [IE11 JavaScript (Error: SCRIPT445) “Object doesn't support this action”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31765353/465053) & [TypeError: Object doesn't support this action in IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47881250/465053)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the **EventSource** in the below code:

```
this.eventsource = new EventSource(this.configService.get("BaseURL"));
```

I got it resolved by adding Event Source Polyfill js. I followed this [EventSource Polyfill](https://github.com/Yaffle/EventSource) link to install the js.

Thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Put `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">` in your index.html
And also check your polyfills script and import all core-js/es6/ scripts

Comment: couldn't find polyfill.ts file, can you please help me out?

Comment: How did you start you app?
With angular starter project?

Comment: Anyway you should have main.ts and polyfills.ts under your src folder

Comment: yeah I have put it the folder but still getting the same issue

Comment: while debugging I found out **this.router.navigate** throws the exception. Still couldn't figure out the issue

Answer (score 0):

Find your `polyfills.ts` file in your angular project folder and import following lines:

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es7/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

If you are using web-animations, so you need this:

```
/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

For evergreen browsers your need this:

```
/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Evergreen browsers definition ([original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19060334/4389078)):

The latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, Internet Explorer, and Safari are evergreen browsers, i.e. they automatically update themselves silently without prompting the user. For Internet Explorer, most people consider this to mean IE10+.

Comment: couldn't find polyfill.ts file, can you please help me out?